# How to access RTF field in popup aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tridion

I am customizing the ribbon toolbar and adding a button to it.Whenever I click on that button,it will open a aspx page allows authors to select some data- onclick of submit button (in popup aspx page) data gets appended to the existing RTF field content.

Our requirement is to replace the portion of the content where the cursor is positioned, with the selected data in the aspx page. Please let me know which object should be used? 
Can we access it through $display.getView().getItem()? Is that information will be present in the "component model object", if so share us the pointers?

Early response will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code of your JavaScript command class and the relevant parts of the ASPX page? Those will make it much easier for people to see what you've already done and may allow them to better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that triggers the popup to open should have a "target" parameter. The target has an "editor" property. You should be able to use the editor to do what you propose. editor.applyHTML will insert HTML at the cursor location. There should be a method that allows you to replace a selection rather than just insert - it might even be the same method, have you tried it?